# Does any std::set implementation not use a red-black tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, b-tree, red-black-tree

Has anyone seen an implementation of the STL where stl::set is *not* implemented as a red-black tree?

The reason I ask is that, in my experiments, B-trees outperform `std::set` (and other red-black tree implementations) by a factor of 2 to 4 depending on the value of B. I'm curious if there is a compelling reason to use red-black trees when there appear to be faster data structures available.

Comment: I'm not an algorithms expert by any means, but `std::set` and friends come with stringent maximum complexity ("big-O") requirements set by the standard. Would an alternative implementation meet all of these requirements?

Comment: you can have a look here: [Why you shouldn't use set (and what you should use instead)](http://lafstern.org/matt/col1.pdf).

Comment: @TristanBrindle: Yes. B-2B trees give the same complexity guarantees.  (In fact, red-black trees are actually a simulation of 2-3-4 trees using binary trees; this makes them more complicated and slower.)

Comment: @davidhigh: I did see that document in my searches. It doesn't answer my question.  It suggests using linear update/search time data structures instead of the O(log n) time structures. That's fine if you don't intend to do many searches or modifications, but stl::set still fills a pretty important role in the STL.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some folks over at Google actually built a [B-tree based implementation of the C++ standard library containers.](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2013/01/c-containers-that-save-memory-and-time.html?m=1) They seem to have much better performance than standard binary tree implementations.

There is a catch, though. The C++ standard guarantees that deleting an element from a map or set only invalidates other iterators pointing to the same element in the map or set. With the B-tree based implementation, due to node splits and consolidations, the erase member functions on these new structures may invalidate iterators to other elements in the tree. As a result, these implementations aren't perfect replacements for the standard implementations and couldn't be used in a conformant implementation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Aha. That's what I was looking for.  I figured there had to be a catch. I didn't realize that the standard allowed for modifications to the tree when there were other iterators into the tree.  This is a pretty non-standard use-case though.  It should be possible to hack around it when it occurs.

Comment: Reading up on the page you pointed to, I see they thoughtfully already provided such a hack: https://code.google.com/p/cpp-btree/wiki/UsageInstructions#Safe_B-Tree_maps_and_sets

Answer (score 4):

There is at least [one implementation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/stlavlmap/) based on AVL trees instead of red-black trees.

I haven't tried to verify conformance of this implementation, but at least (unlike a B-tree based implementation) it at least *could* be written to conform perfectly to the requirements of the standard.

Comment: I'm not sure AVL trees will do; `insert` and `erase` require amortized constant modification times when changing a known location, and AVL trees don't supply this.

Comment: Unfortunately it is GNU GPL licensed.